# Is it possible to hide some topics in phpBB forum?

Tags: phpbb

I would like to be able to hide some of the topics in a phpBB-based forum temporarily from the users - perhaps with the exception of administrators and moderators.

I am using the forum for my students and I have solutions of some problems from exams and tests there - posted either by me or by some of the students. I plan to use the same or very similar problems during the next academic year. So I don't want the students to see them, but I want to make the solutions visible again after the tests; so that I do not have to post solutions to same questions again.

Is something like this possible? Is this a standard part of phpBB, or do I need to install some modification(s) for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a PDF ([PHPBB3 admin guide](http://citizen.apps.gov/docs/Beta_phpBB_Administrator_Guide_v2.pdf) especially from page 9 to 11) it will help you create group permissions for a specific "sub-forum" (for phpBB3 as written in the link name).

But if you're free to use any platform I recommend using [Moodle Course Management System](http://moodle.org/) instead of PHP-BB in your case . It's a pretty powerful tool for...well online course management.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the suggestion is to create a new sub-forum - which will be invisible - and move the posts I want to hide to the subforum. Is that right? (Perhaps I should have stated in my question more clearly that some of the questions should be left visible, I want to hide only some of them. Anyway, this solution would give me basically the same thing.)

Comment: I'm saying that you can set a board for your answers and another board invisible if you don't have the right permissions. For example you could create a board like "students" available for every one in your course and another one "Exams and Solutions" locked by filtered access (permission) and when you want to open the board you set the permission for the student group so they can enter